# How to update Windows 10 on an external boot drive

Tags: windows

I have a Macbook Pro that I boot into Windows 10 via an external SSD running Windows 10 version 1803. I'd like to upgrade to Windows 10 1H2021, the current version, but windows update says I'm up to date, and the Windows Update Tool runs, downloads the update, and then halts telling me that "You can't update windows if it's on an external USB drive".

So... how do I update my Windows 10 installation? Or do I need to wipe the drive and reinstall *everything* from scratch?

Thank you

Comment: Windows to Go installs cannot be upgraded, you might be able to edit the key responsible for blocking feature updates, but you might also break the install by making that change

Comment: Thank you for your answer which is, I suppose, definitive, and would explain why windows update says it's up to date. That sort of restriction is odd - not sure why microsoft would take the time to check what sort of media windows is on, but whatever.

Comment: They don’t check, the registry key, just blocks feature updates. Microsoft never explained the reason they prevent Windows 2 Go installs from being updated. Since they discontinued supporting Windows 2 Go two years ago for performance reasons they probably won’t